# can't convert String into Integer on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having an error:

> TypeError in PrintsController#update
>
> can't convert String into Integer

The form code i am using is:

```
<%= form_for @print do |f| %>
....
....

<%= f.fields_for :blackwhites_attributes do |blackwhite| %>
<%= blackwhite.select :newpages , options_for_select((1..(@print.number_of_images_entry)).to_a), {}, :multiple => true, :size => @print.number_of_images_entry %>
<% end %>
```

while in my development.log, i am seeing there is an empty value in the "newpages" select field.

```
>      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xAs20vFEt3vEBOhFugOyR0nWIgkoMJ0d4JPbl5E5VQ4=",
> "print"=>{"quantity"=>"1", "blackwhites_attributes"=>{"newpages"=>["",
> "2", "3"]}, "comment"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Print", "id"=>"5"}
>       User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1000 LIMIT 1
>       Print Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `prints`.* FROM `prints` WHERE `prints`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "5"]]
>       SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
>        (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
>     Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms
```

My blackwhite model has "serialize" as well for the array of numbers to be stored into the database:

```
class Blackwhite < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :newpages, :print_id

  serialize :newpages

  belongs_to :print

end
```

But i am finding the problem would be having the Print controller update not building the form and i have the build in the Prints_controller

```
  def update
    @print = Print.find(params[:id])
    @print.blackwhites.build
      if @print.update_attributes(params[:print])
        redirect_to @print, :flash => { :success  => "Successfully updated your Print Order." }
      else
      render :action => 'edit'
      end
 end
```

Print Model:

```
    class Print < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :blackwhites
      belongs_to :user

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :blackwhites, :allow_destroy => true

      attr_accessible :comment, :document, :document_file_name,
                            :document_file_size, :document_updated_at, :is_printing,
                            :is_processing_image, :user_id, :document_content_type,
                            :number_of_images_entry, :is_delivered, :quantity, :blackwhites_attributes

...
...

      end
```

Comment: can you posts the code og print model

Comment: added the print model.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: I bet the `@print.number_of_images_entry` returns a string, and not an integer. try to do: `@print.number_of_images_entry.to_i` on all occurrences of that.

Comment: @Cort3z - to_i doesn't fix the problem. :(

Comment: The error starts happening when i added @print.blackwhites.build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty string is probably the default value for the select. You can configure the helper not to use one, by making sure :include_blank and :prompt are not set to something truthy.

Another potential solution is to get rid of the

```
attr_accessible :newpages
```

and replace it with

```
def newpages
  self[:newpages].map(&:presence).compact
end
```

and/or

```
def newpages=(ary)
  self[:newpages] = ary.map(&:presence).compact
end
```

Lastly, a better overall solution is to use the FormObject pattern instead of accepts_nested_attributes. Then you have total control over how your models are built and persisted. See item #3 here: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Comment: Understood the part of using Virtus gem in the URL (except i load the .rb file in lib/ folder for the class - still trying to figure it out)... and the code solution above i had tried does not solve the problem. (I had used in the blackwhite model) - error is the same as the title.